# django-otp and dj-stripe conflict

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

i'm searching a way to implement django-otp and dj-stripe in a web project but i think there is a conflict because django-otp uses custom admin_site.register() to register models while dj-stripe uses admin.site.register().

i'm triyng with the following code but not works because all stripe model are registered not following list_display field customizations as in admin.py on github repository.

```
#urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from account.admin import admin_site

urlpatterns = [
path("realadmin/", admin_site.urls),
path("stripe/", include("djstripe.urls", namespace="djstripe")),
]

#admin.py
from django_otp.admin import OTPAdminSite
from django_otp.plugins.otp_totp.models import TOTPDevice
from django_otp.plugins.otp_totp.admin import TOTPDeviceAdmin
# Stripe modules
from djstripe import models

class OTPAdmin(OTPAdminSite):
   pass

admin_site = OTPAdmin(name='OTPAdmin')

# Script to register all models
modelsarray = django.apps.apps.get_models()

# Register other django-otp models with the custom admin site (admin_site)
for model in modelsarray:
    try:
        if model.__module__.startswith("dj-stripe"):
            # Register with the default admin.site for dj-stripe models
            admin.site.register(model)
        elif model == Customer:
            admin_site.register(model, CustomerAdmin)
    
        else:
            # Register with the custom admin site for other models (e.g., django-otp)
            admin_site.register(model)

    except admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered:
        pass
```

so, i want to register stripe's models using admin.site.register because in this way i can use admin.py code of github repository but i need also to use admin_site.register for otp secutiry tool.

can anyone help me, please?